# Sort Y axis by Sum (yield) of Waseca with descending order

Tags: python, altair

I'm attempting to sort Y axis based on the descending order of sum(yield) of Waseca site. How can I do that?

Thanks a lot.

https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/horizontal_stacked_bar_chart.html

Source code:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.barley()

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='sum(yield)',
    y='variety',
    color='site'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sort` parameter within the encoding you want to sort as per https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/bar_chart_sorted.html

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.barley()

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='sum(yield)',
    y=alt.Y('variety', sort='-x'),
    color='site'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @joelostblom. I am attempting to add stacked bar chart with text overlay as per: https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/stacked_bar_chart_with_text.html, but I didn't know how to do that. Hope you help to take a look of chart via my simple code: https://www.kaggle.com/interphuoc0101/times-use?scriptVersionId=55599358.

Comment: @Childream It doesn't seem like you have used `mark_text` in as in the example, try adding that. If you have more issues with the text, please ask a new question and feel free to link it here. Don't forget to accept this solution with the green checkmark if it helped you so that this question gets marked as resolved.

Comment: Sorry because I'm new to this platform so I dont know how to accept the solution by getting marked with the green checkmark. It's already done as your help. I will try adding `mark_text` and link in case of having issues. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Im try adding mark_text but it didn't work as expected. I have just asked a new question at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66453074/stacked-text-in-a-stacked-bar-chart-using-altair-mark-text. Hope your helps @joelostblom. Thank you so much.