# altair bar chart text issue

Tags: bar-chart, altair

this is my code ...please correct so that label will show correct count.
tool tip is showing correct count.

```
bars =alt.Chart(r).transform_fold(
   ['Reservation_count', 'ON_ACCOUNT'],
  as_=['column', 'value']
).mark_bar().encode( 
  x='month:N',
  y='value:Q', 
  color=alt.Color('column:N', scale=alt.Scale(range=["#f50520", "#bab6b7"])),  
  tooltip=alt.Tooltip(['ON_ACCOUNT','Reservation_count']),
   )
text = bars.mark_text(
    align='left',
    color='black',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=0,dy=-8  # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
).encode( 
    text=alt.Text('ON_ACCOUNT:Q', format='.0f') 
   ) 

rule = alt.Chart(r).mark_rule(color='red').encode(
    y='mean(Reservation_count):Q'
)   

(bars+text+rule).properties(width=490,height=310)
```

below is my data:

```
month   ON_ACCOUNT  Reservation_count
0   1   22          134
1   2   32          137
2   3   22          135
3   4   21          113
4   5   18          120
5   6   17          90
6   7   26          83
7   8   11          86
8   9   11          102
9   10  2           68
```

please help me with this altair bar chart..two columns are there `Reservation_count` and `ON_ACCOUNT` LABEL IS showing the same number for both ...

Thanks

for example last bar showing 2,2  both labels it should be top 2 and bottom 68

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short version answer to your question is to use `text=alt.Text('value:Q', format='.0f')`.

But there are a few more issues with your code:

1. You are expanding your text layer from the bar plot, which already has the color parameter set. This will ignore the color setting of the text layer.
   You can use a data encoding free from any color specification. You can then use this encoding to build your bar and text layers with their color settings.
2. I encountered the text ordering issue discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66453074/stacked-text-in-a-stacked-bar-chart-using-altair-mark-text), and none of the given solutions worked out. However, changing the plot from vertical bar to horizontal bars seem to resolve the issue. This is potentially a bug.
3. Since you are plotting the mean of `Reservation_count` parameter on a stacked plot, the information might be misleading. I would suggest a layered bar instead of a stacked one. Surprisingly, this seems to solve the issue of text order.

Here is the code:

```
base =alt.Chart(r).transform_fold(
   ['Reservation_count', 'ON_ACCOUNT'],
  as_=['column', 'value']
)
bars = base.mark_bar().encode( 
  x='month:N',
  y=alt.X('value:Q', stack=None), # stack =None enables layered bar
  color=alt.Color('column:N', scale=alt.Scale(range=["#f50520", "#bab6b7"])),  
  tooltip=alt.Tooltip(['ON_ACCOUNT','Reservation_count']),
  #order=alt.Order('color_Category_sort_index:Q'),
   )
text = base.mark_text(
    
    align='center',
    color='black',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=0,dy=-8,  # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
    #order=alt.Order('color_Category_sort_index:Q'),
).encode( 
    x='month:N',
    y='value:Q', 
    text=alt.Text('value:Q', format='.0f') 
   ) 

rule = alt.Chart(r).mark_rule(color='red').encode(
    y='mean(Reservation_count):Q'
)   

(bars+text+rule).properties(width=490,height=310)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your support....understood your explanation

Comment: Boss....i get the chart...sorted by month.. ..but instead of month if i put other field ...it is not sorting....kindly Help......below is my new  chart....Thanks

Comment: Reservation_branch_code ON_ACCOUNT Rcount
0 1101                          46                         1242
1 1103                           34                         388...........want to sort by Reservation_branch_code